# Trying to convert Stacked BarPlot from D3 to Aframe

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, webgl, aframe

As the title suggests, I am trying to convert a Stacked BarPlot from D3 (version 4) to Aframe (using the AR.js library).

The D3 example I am using can be found here:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html

When I run the code in the browser, I can see 4 boxes (squares), stacked on top of the other corresponding boxes, however in a weird, layered fashion. I believe this is due to my 'scale' and 'position' attributes which are incorrectly reading in the data and rendering like they should. Or perhaps it's how I appended the "a-entity" and then "a-box" to my "a-scene". Or perhaps it's neither / both (?)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe- 
ar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe- 
extras.loaders.min.js"></script>
<script>
THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = 
'https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js/master/three.js/'
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@3.2.5/dist/aframe- 
animation-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-randomizer-components@3.0.2/dist/aframe- 
randomizer-components.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-entity-generator-component@3.0.1/dist/aframe- 
entity-generator-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor- 
component/master/dist/aframe-mouse-cursor-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">

<div id="data_by_age"></div>

<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; 
sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; displayWidth: 1280; displayHeight: 960; 
debugUIEnabled: false;'>

<a-entity gps-entity-place="longitude: -73.766327; latitude: 41.032730;">
    <a-cursor fuse="true" color="yellow"></a-cursor>
</a-entity>
    <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera>

</a-scene>

<script type="text/javascript">

byAge();

function byAge() {

var scene = d3.select("a-scene");

d3.csv("../static/sample.csv", function(data) {

var subgroups = data.columns.slice(1)

var groups = d3.map(data, function(d){return(d.group)}).keys()

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(subgroups)
.range(['#011f4b','#03396c','#005b96', '#6497b1', '#b3cde0'])

var stackedData = d3.stack()
.keys(subgroups)
(data)

var data_scle = [];
var data_pos = [];

scene
.append("a-entity")
.selectAll("a-entity")
.data(stackedData)
.enter()
.append('a-entity')
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
.selectAll("a-box")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("a-box")
.attr('rotation', '0 180 0')

.attr('scale', function (d,i) {
    return d + " " + d + " " + d;
})
// .attr('scale', function (d,i) {
//     var x =  i * 10;
//         var y = d;
//         var z = d;
//     data_scle[i] = {"x": x, "y": y, "z": z};
//     return x+" "+y+" "+z;
// })
.attr('position', function(d,i) {
    var x =  i * 175;
        // var y = 0;
        var y = d;
        var z = -500;
    data_pos[i] = {"x": x, "y": y, "z": z};
    return x+" "+y+" "+z;
  })

})

};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my csv file:

```
group, stronglyAgree, somewhatAgree, stronglyDisagree, notSureNoOpinion
eighteen, 21, 22, 11, 18, 28
thirtyfive, 33, 29, 11, 5, 22
fortyfive, 36, 23, 9, 8, 24
sixtyfive, 42, 24, 7, 10, 17
```

I've also seen github repos tailored specifically for making stacked bar chart components in Aframe, however I couldn't seem to get it to work properly.

https://github.com/fran-aguilar/a-framedc/tree/master/src/components/barchartstack

Any help would be immensely appreciated.